# Не работает при адаптивности

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Код

```
if ($('#ocfilter').is(':hidden')) {
                $('#navbar-ocfilter').html($('#ocfilter').remove().get(0).outerHTML);

                var html = $('#ocfilter-mobile').remove().get(0).outerHTML;

                $('.breadcrumb').after(html);

                options['mobile'] = true;
            }

            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#ocfilter').ocfilter(options);
            }, 1);
        });
```

Не работает как я понимаю эта часть кода (при адаптивке) точней if ($('#ocfilter').is(':hidden')) {
Скрин должно быть так - http://joxi.ru/EA4NVEbswyE44m
Но сразу же все открыто - http://joxi.ru/n2Y8jG0foBzJNm

То есть как я понимаю логику

```
<div class="panel ocfilter panel-default" id="ocfilter" aria-expanded="false">
```

отсюда вырезаем и вставляем эту часть кода сюда

```
<div id="navbar-ocfilter" class="navbar-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false"></div>
```

Comment: Что не работает ?

Comment: @Duoxx shop5.alicom.dp.ua/amunitsiya joxi.ru/L21LVMJS8xlL0m При адаптивке Блок вырезается и вставляется в другой что-бы работало по кнопке меню. Но этого не происходит как как блок не вырезался)